# Too much recursion in Firefox when using custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web-component, custom-element

I am trying to create new custom elements.

I have a very simple html index file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="dist/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>WebComponents</h1>
        <hello-world></hello-world>

        <script src="src/components/hello-world.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My *hello-world* component is as follows :

```
class HelloWorldElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor(){
        super()

        this.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello Meetup !</h1>`;
    }    

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log("I'm here!");
    }

    disconnectedCallback(){
        console.log("I'm gone!");
    }

}

    window.customElements.define(
                    'hello-world', 
                     HelloWorldElement);
```

This code snippet works perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari.

I have added the **webcomponents-lite.js** import to add support for other browsers.

However when trying to run the code in Firefox I get the following error:

```
too much recursion
[Learn More]
webcomponents-lite.js:93:170
```

I have found very little info on the web as to what can be going on.

I think I am following the recommended path explained in the [polyfills page](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills/) from the web components website.

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

EDIT:

I am able to get the custom element showing by enabling **dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled** and **dom.webcomponents.enabled** in the firefox config and removing the polyfill, but that's obviously not something desired on production.

Comment: I also see that other websites such as https://component.kitchen/tutorial work fine in Firefox so there MUST be something wrong with the HTML above

Answer (score 4):

The error is due to the fact that you modify the inner HTML content of the custom element in its `constructor`, which is unexpected and therefore should not be done.

Instead, you should do that after, for example in the `connectedCallback()` method.

Alternately, if you want to define the content in the `constructor`, you should insert it into a Shadow DOM.

NB: the custom element polyfill is effectively included in **webcomponents-lite.js**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if the shadow dom could help. Any idea why the code works fine if I import the custom elements polyfill manually?

Comment: @jlengrand maybe it's because it's another part of the polyfill the makes the script fail (the Shadow DOM polyfill part I think)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it looks like I was missing another polyfill?

If I also import

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js"></script>
```

before the **web-components-lite.js** polyfill then I have no issues any more. I found the resource via [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#browser_support)

This is weird, as I thought that custom-elements was one of the subparts of the web-components polyfill itself...